# Can we change packages in Linux from scratch?

Tags: lfs

I've tried to compile Linux through [Linux from scratch Version 7.5](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) and I can't compile some packages because as I realize and googled them, they have some bugs, for example I couldn't compile gcc 4.8. 2 but gcc 4.9. 1 compiled just fine so my questions are:

Can I replace some of the packages with older or newer packages? Does it cause some issue in future?

Answer (score 1):

From their [general FAQ:](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/faq/#why-not-version)

> **Can I use a version newer than the one in the Book?**
>
> > If this is your first time building LFS, using a version not in the book or varying from the book in any way is not a good idea. The IRC channel regulars have a saying, "FBBG", meaning "Follow Book, Book Good." They and the people on the lists have helped many an unhappy newbie who deviated from the book during that first build.
> >
> > Once you've built a system "by the book", you have a stable knowledge base from which to experiment to your heart's content (or pain, as is often the case.)

I guess they say that for a reason.